# Less than or equal on top of greater than or equal

Tags: amssymb

I found the commands $\gtrless$ and $\lessgtr$ in the package "amssymb".

https://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/amssymb-symbols.pdf

I could not find a similar command with that add an equal sign to each, that is $\geq$ on top of $\leq$ and vice versa. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Please can you draw your symbols?

Comment: Do you mean `\overset{\geq}{\leq}`?

Comment: OP please enlighten us what it's supposed to mean? Because mathematically it just gives 0 information about any relation between a and b

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\gele{\mathrel{\hstretch{1.5}{%
  \stackanchor[1pt]{\scriptscriptstyle\geq}{\scriptscriptstyle\leq}}}}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$a \gele b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or...if you want the symbol as wide as the original components,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\gele{\mathrel{\stackanchor[1pt]{\vstretch{.5}{\geq}}{\vstretch{.5}{\leq}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \gele b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 though I'm not sure what this perverse symbol is supposed to mean 

Comment: @campa I was thinking the same...if it is greater than or equal to **or** less than or equal to, it seems something of a tautology.

Answer (score 5):

You can do as follows, but… what should this mean?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gele}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\gele@{\ge\le}}}
\newcommand{\lege}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\gele@{\le\ge}}}
\newcommand{\gele@}[2]{\gele@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\gele@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \sbox\z@{$#1\mkern3mu$}%
    \ialign{##\cr$#1#2$\cr\noalign{\vskip\wd\z@}$#1#3$\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
X\gele Y\lege Z
\]

\begin{center}
$X\gele Y\lege Z$ \\[2ex]
$\scriptstyle X\gele Y\lege Z$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$a \rlap{\raisebox{0.7ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\geq$}}%
  \raisebox{0.26ex}{\rotatebox{180}{$\scriptscriptstyle\geq$}} b$
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]